# Unrecognized XSLTC extension 'http://exslt.org/common:document''

Tags: xslt-1.0

```
 <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl"

 <exsl:document href="filename">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </exsl:document>
```

exsl not working with XSLT 1.0, I want to create multiple files using XSLT 1.0 only. How to do it ?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to create multiple files using XSLT 1.0 only.

XSLT 1.0 as such does not allow for multiple result documents. You will need an XSLT 1.0 processor that either supports the EXSLT `<exsl:document>` element or provides a similar feature as a custom extension. Or program multiple conversions, using the calling application.

Comment: @nNidhi you can look for further information : http://www.exslt.org/exsl/elements/document/

Comment: I tried with this but still not getting the desired results

Comment: @Nidhi Which processor are you using? Not all XSLT 1.0 processors support the EXSLT <exsl:document> extension element. Judging by the error message in your title, neither does yours.